# Custom Uninstalling menu android

Tags: android

I have an android app that's related to security.

My need is authenticate user before uninstallation. ie; if anyone tries to uninstall my app it pops up a window and read some password/id or something and if its valid uninstallation proceeds else not.

I have root access

Answer (score 2):

That's against the rules of android eco system. all users should be allowed to uninstall their apps.

The only way to achieve it is to have your app installed as a system app, and they won't be able to uninstall the app unless they have a rooted device.

Another way that is not recommended is to monitor the logs (not supported from API 16 and above, but possible if you have root) and do something when you find out the user has reached the dialog of uninstallation of your app.

Comment: my phone is rooted .that's y Iam moving to this topic

Comment: so if you put the app's apk file into /system/app and restart the OS, it should become a system app that nobody can uninstall without root permission.

Comment: thats not iam asking for i need to uninstall by custom password

Comment: the above said all are familiar to me also ,but my need is different anyway thanks for answering me

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on Android officially without firmware modifications.

At best, you can have the user make your app the device admin, which will prevent it from being uninstalled until removed from device admins.

Or since you have root, you could scan the logcat for a message saying something like (exact wording may vary from device to device):

```
Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.DELETE dat=package:your.package cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.UninstallerActivity }
```

Once you get this message, launch a popup Activity that requires a password to be dismissed.

Comment: Thats enough how can i be a admin to authenticate the app uninstallation?

Comment: u said "you can have the user make your app the device admin, which will prevent it from being uninstalled until removed from device admins" This is what i want how i can achieve this